# MVC4: Getting Active Directory User Guid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Once a user is logged into a Windows-Authentication site, how do I get their Active Directoy user guid from the User.

Eg in an Action:

```
ViewBag.Message = User.Identity.GUID????
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find the current user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;

if(user != null)
{
   // get guid
   var userGuid = user.Guid;
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Answer (score -2):

```
 string userName = user.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];

            using (var oRoot = new DirectoryEntry(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAPDomain"], null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
            {
                using (var deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(oRoot))
                {
                    deSearch.Filter = string.Format("(&(sAMAccountName={0}))", userName);
                    SearchResult searchResult = deSearch.FindOne();
                    if (searchResult != null)
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry de = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry();

                    }
                }
            }
```